# numpy linspace and mesh grid for multiple dimensions

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am porting some matlab code to python using numpy and I have the following matlab command:

```
[xgrid,ygrid]=meshgrid(linspace(-0.5,0.5, GridSize-1), ...
                       linspace(-0.5,0.5, GridSize-1));
```

Now, this is fine in 2D but I would like to extend this to n-dimensional. So depending on the input data, GridSize can be a 2, 3 or 4 dimensional vector. So, in 2D this would be:

```
[xgrid, grid] = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-0.5,0.5, GridSize[0]), 
                            np.linspace(-0.5,0.5, GridSize[1]));
```

However, I do not know the dimensions of the input before, so is it possible to rewrite this expression, so that it can generate grids with arbitrary number of dimensions?

Comment: have you tried adding a coma and another linspace?

Comment: Yeah, but the point is that the dimensions are not known at "compile time"... It has to be generated based on the dimensions of the input GridSize vector.

Comment: Your MATLAB code uses the same size for both dimensions, your numpy code not. What is intended?

Comment: It does not use the same size even though the Matlab code does not.

Comment: @Luca  If they are not known, put an if statement..... Also, in matlab, any matrix has infinite dimensions size 1, so you could just add alinspace with asingle point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use loop comprehension to generate all 1D arrays and then use [`np.meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) on all those with `*` operator that internally does [`unpacking of argument lists`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), which is equivalent of [`MATLAB's comma separated lists`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html), like so -

```
allG = [np.linspace(-0.5,0.5, G) for G in GridSize]
out = np.meshgrid(*allG)
```

**Sample runs**

1) 2D Case :

```
In [27]: GridSize = [3,4]

In [28]: allG = [np.linspace(-0.5,0.5, G) for G in GridSize]
    ...: out = np.meshgrid(*allG)
    ...: 

In [29]: out[0]
Out[29]: 
array([[-0.5,  0. ,  0.5],
       [-0.5,  0. ,  0.5],
       [-0.5,  0. ,  0.5],
       [-0.5,  0. ,  0.5]])

In [30]: out[1]
Out[30]: 
array([[-0.5       , -0.5       , -0.5       ],
       [-0.16666667, -0.16666667, -0.16666667],
       [ 0.16666667,  0.16666667,  0.16666667],
       [ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.5       ]])
```

2) 3D Case :

```
In [51]: GridSize = [3,4,2]

In [52]: allG = [np.linspace(-0.5,0.5, G) for G in GridSize]
    ...: out = np.meshgrid(*allG)
    ...: 

In [53]: out[0]
Out[53]: 
array([[[-0.5, -0.5],
        [ 0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0.5,  0.5]], ...

       [[-0.5, -0.5],
        [ 0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0.5,  0.5]]])

In [54]: out[1]
Out[54]: 
array([[[-0.5       , -0.5       ], ...

       [[ 0.16666667,  0.16666667],
        [ 0.16666667,  0.16666667],
        [ 0.16666667,  0.16666667]],

       [[ 0.5       ,  0.5       ],
        [ 0.5       ,  0.5       ],
        [ 0.5       ,  0.5       ]]])

In [55]: out[2]
Out[55]: 
array([[[-0.5,  0.5], ....

       [[-0.5,  0.5],
        [-0.5,  0.5],
        [-0.5,  0.5]]])
```

Comment: That did the trick. I was tying to use list comprehension but missed the `*` operator and could not understand my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: @Luca No worries, glad to help!